# In jq, how can I combine two objects so the output is comma separated in one line?

Tags: jq

I thought this would be simple, but I'm stumped.

In jq, how can I take this input...

```
{
  "foo": "bar"
}
{
  "foo": "baz"
}
```

...and get this output?

```
bar,baz
```

Comment: For the question as you had it with double quotes around the output, you could use `jq -sr 'map(.foo) | @csv'` – the CSV filter *does* add quotes around strings, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way

`jq -nr '[inputs|.foo]|join(",")'`

or like this

`jq -sr 'map(.foo)|join(",")'`

The idea is to get bar and baz into an array and then join the elements of the array with ",".

-r gives you output without quotes.